# Windows Terminal: Run a command when starting wsl and keeping the shell open

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

In Windows Terminal, you can create a profile and add some start-up command (through `commandline` option in `settings.json` file. So when you start your profile, WT is executing the command, but then it's exiting (we can see for a second the new tab).

**When starting a `wsl` profile in Windows Terminal, how can I execute linux commands AND keeping the current shell open?** (so I can see the result, and keep on typing commands).

**NB:** I want to keep the current shell. [This workaround](https://superuser.com/a/1643870) start another shell, so that does not work here:

```json
"commandline": "wsl -e bash -c \"foobar=`ls -a`; echo $foobar; exec bash\"",
```

```
. .. .bash_aliases .bash_history .bash_logout .bashrc .lesshsQ .lesshst .profile .ssh .viminfo .vimrc
test@xxx:~$ echo $foobar

test@xxx:~$
```

---

If the profile is Powershell, we have `-NoExit`:

```json
"commandline": "powershell.exe -NoExit \"<Your command goes here>\"",
```

If the profile is CMD, we have the `/k` flag:

```json
"commandline": "cmd /k \"<Your command goes here>\"",
```

I didn't find the wsl equivalent.

---

**Related:**

- [Windows Terminal: run CLI command on start up](https://superuser.com/questions/1506211/windows-terminal-run-cli-command-on-start-up)
- [How can I open WSL terminal with a command without it automatically closing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1643699/how-can-i-open-wsl-terminal-with-a-command-without-it-automatically-closing)
- [How to start WSL in windows terminal programmatically and run command](https://superuser.com/questions/1578661/how-to-start-wsl-in-windows-terminal-programmatically-and-run-command)

Windows Terminal version: 1.15.3465.0 - Wsl 2 running Debian bullseye 11.6

Comment: This isn't exactly a wsl problem. With `-c` bash will not remain once the command line passed is executed (similar to running the line with `exec` I think). `--rcfile` is the only workaround I can think of that fulfill your need.

Comment: Based on the example you provided, can you just change it to `export foobar=$(ls -a); echo $foobar; exec bash`?  `foobar` would then be available in the replacement shell.

Comment: @TomYan If I'm not mistaken, `/f` cmd flag and `-NoExit` powershell option are doing exactly what I need, so yes it is definitely related to `wsl` . I will look into `--rcfile` but using a file is not really convenient. Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes, I know, but my point was giving an example to show that this is not the same shell ;)

Comment: @4wk_ The role of wsl in this matter is like a "runner" that starts / run the Linux shell (bash or anything you like) ; even if wsl had something like `-NoExit`, it cannot change the way how bash runs a command or determine whether the shell will exit, unless bash itself has a switch for you to change how it works (so that e.g. wsl can translate its `-NoExit` to a switch that gets passed to bash). Put it in another way, even if wsl allows you to prevent itself from quitting, you'll just get an "empty" terminal or whatever that has no shell / process running.

Comment: Thanks Tom Yan and @NotTheDr01ds, your comments here helped me resolve my similar question on passing [environment variables to wsl](https://superuser.com/questions/1762168/launch-wsl-from-windows-terminal-with-different-environment-variables)

Comment: @TomYan oh, very interesting indeed, thank you. So can we say (oversimplifying): `terminal start wsl => wsl start bash => bash run commands` and `terminal start powershell (or cmd) => powershell (or cmd) run commands`?

Comment: Yes, pretty much like that.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @TomYan in the comments, the `--rcfile` option is probably the only real way to do this.  You mentioned that you'd like to avoid the use of a file, though, which can also be accomplished (courtesy a WSL/WT-modified version of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152028/11810933) and process-substitution )with:

```
wsl -e bash -c "exec bash --rcfile <(echo 'source ~/.bashrc; foobar=$(ls -a)')"
```

Keep in mind that Windows Terminal profiles seem to use `CMD` quoting and escaping rules.  So keep an eye out for any "gotchas" if your command fails, and test it from the *Command Prompt* (`CMD`) profile first to see errors reported.

If you were doing this from PowerShell, the quoting/escaping rules would be a bit different.  I'd recommend using [Here-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#here-strings):

```
wsl -e bash -c @'
exec bash --rcfile <(echo 'source ~/.bashrc; foobar=$(ls -a)')
'@
```

For most users, however, try the following first to see if it meets your needs:

```
wsl -e bash -c \"export foobar=$(ls -a); echo $foobar; exec bash\""
```

If the need is to get a variable injected into the new shell, then `export`'ing the variable before running the new shell may be the best bet.  In your use-case, however, you mentioned that this wasn't a viable option.

There are a few more ideas in [this Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123103/432493) question.